# Django processing data in different process

Tags: python, django, mqtt, communication

I am currently planning a django project which consists of two parts. The normal django application and an additional application which uses MQTT to read sensors. For better loading times for the HTTP responses, I planned to receive the MQTT publish messages in an external process or thread and write it into the database used by django. The sensor data in this database then is always used whenever a HTTP request is made.

Do you guys have any better architectural solutions to my problem?

Best regards

Comment: I believe you are in need of something asynchronous, have you heard about Redis or RabbitMQ from Celery? I use both solutions to work with receiving data daily at midnight.

Comment: Yeah, I need "something" asynchronous. But I am pretty sure Celery is overkill. Tbh I am just wondering if I can access the ORM of django from another thread

Comment: I don't believe Celery is overkill, its basic implementation makes you run async jobs only, nothing too surreal, with queues and so on, so don't take a look at their Hello World. [Link](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

Comment: If it is a new project, not in a hurry. You can start testing with Django 3.0, according to this [link]
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/3.0/) he will have async jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Django background tasks](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) could be a simple way of doing what you need.

It uses your existing database to run tasks in the background and is very easy to set up. It also supports scheduling repeated tasks.